# cloud_package.cspkg file was not created after installing "socket.io-servicebus"

Tags: node.js, azure

I'd like to use the **"socket.io-servicebus"** module to my node.js application.

But I encountered that a problem.
After installing the "socket.io-servicebus", cloud_package.cspkg file was not created by "Publish-AzureServiceProject" command.

I'm using "Windows Azure PowerShell" on Windows7 64bit edition.

Here is the procedure.

- New-AzureServiceProject test1
- Add-AzureNodeWebRole www
- cd www
- npm install socket.io-servicebus
- Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName xxx ...

  [ cloud_package.cspkg will not created ]

By the way "`Start-AzureEmulator -Launch"` will be succeeded and we can test own application.

Please give me some advices. thank you.

Comment: I have this exact same problem! It would be great if you could share how you resolved this.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the issue here is due to a known path length limitation. Azure has a limitation on paths in the package being more than 255 chars and in this case bringing in socket.io WITH all of it's dependencies is hitting that path.

There are several possible work arounds here.

**A.** - Zip up node modules and extract on the server.

Basically you zip up your modules and publish the module zip within the package. Then you can use an Azure startup task (in your cscfg) on the server to unzip the files.

Publish-AzureServicePackage will grab anything in the project, so in this case you just have a little script that you run before publishing which creates the node_modules archive and deletes node_modules.

I am planning to do a blog post on this, but it is actually relatively easy to do.

**B.** - Download node modules dynamically

You can download modules in the cloud. This can also be done with a startup task as is shown [here](http://nodeblog.azurewebsites.net/startup-task-to-run-npm-in-azure).

If you look in that post you will see how you can author a startup task if you decide to do the archive route.

Feel free to ping me with any questions.

Comment: Mr. Glenn Block,
Sorry, I have no time to check your response today.

In fact, I'm using the Azure platform provided by Fujitsu which name is FGCP/A5.
Therefore I have to deploy my cloud_package.cspkg file separately from the normal  command.
That's my additional information.

Thank you very much for your help.